# Cannot get version 2 transactions to work on private testnet

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, ringct, testnet

I built Monero private testnet (basically used these instructions https://github.com/moneroexamples/private-testnet, but with the latest codebase).
Everything seemed to work fine, but I realized that transactions created by the wallet have tx.version=1 in cryptonote_tx_utils.cpp

```
tx.version = rct ? 2 : 1;
```

It looks the boolean rct variable is calculated using earliest_height, which is based on m_earliest_height. Basically, this code appears to look at the block height where a fork is activated and apply true or false based on that. 
There is something strange going on, specifically m_earliest_height is basically composed of extremely large numbers (maximums of unsigned integers). So, it looks like 'rct' would never actually be true (because it would take some enormous block height to activate it). The code that generates m_earliest_height strange huge integers is in node_rpc_proxy.cpp.
When I try to overwrite max integers and add something like block 1000 for earliest_height (because testnet node is about 2000 blocks only), I actually get tx.version 2 and everything seems normal.
But then it says that 'transaction was rejected by daemon with status (Failed)'.

Can you please help me figure how to actually work with ringct transactions by making sure that tx.version 2 is enabled and node accepts it? Much thanks.
Thank you. I tried to modify hard fork heights like so:

```
    testnet_hard_forks[] = {
  // version 1 from the start of the blockchain
  { 1, 1, 0, 1341378000 },

  // version 2 starts from block 624634, which is on or around the 23rd of November, 2015. Fork time finalised on 2015-11-20. No fork voting occurs for the v2 fork.
  { 2, 100, 0, 1341378000+1000},

  // versions 3-5 were passed in rapid succession from September 18th, 2016
  { 3, 200, 0, 1341378000+10000 },
  { 4, 300, 0, 1341378000+11000 },
  { 5, 500, 0, 1341378000+11100 }, // add 5 months on testnet to shut the update warning up since there's a large gap to v6

  { 6, 1000, 0, 1341378000+11199 },
  { 7, 2000, 0, 1341378000+11900 },
  { 8, 1057058, 0, 1515967497 },
};
static const uint64_t testnet_hard_fork_version_1_till = 99;
```

But the node gets stuck on block 100 this way (I see it by doing 'diff' command). I see that the stagenet part of the code does something like this, so not sure why it is not working. Could you help me to get testnet to current version (but without bulletproofs)?

Comment: Did you modify the code ? If so, how ? What is your current height ? v2 txes start at 801219.

Answer (score 1):

As dEBRUYNE told me once on reddit:

```
Testnet has different forks (and fork heights), which can be found here:  
https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp#L120
```

You should edit the forks height and recompile to get your testnet to the HF where it has been implemented (v5 if I'm correct for testnet).

Comment: Thank you. I tried to modify hard fork heights. I edited my original question to reflect what I did. Much thanks for feedback.

Comment: If anyone has an idea of how to edit the fork height in the node, so it picks up ringct, please help me out. thanks.

Comment: The fourth number seems to be a timestamp. Could you play with it so it's accurate and see what happens?

Comment: It appears to be a Unix timestamp in seconds. So, for each block difference it should be 120 seconds difference, is that what you mean by accurate? When I look at the original code that I commented out, I see that   { 3, 800500, 0, 1472415034 },
    { 4, 801219, 0, 1472415035 },

Comment: Which means that a difference of 719 blocks corresponds to 1 second difference in the code that worked. I am just trying to figure out what you mean by 'accurate'.

Comment: I think what happens is that the node does accept my changes, but somehow it sets current blockchain height for that node equal to the v2 HF value. I see a hint of that (I think) on line 1990 of blockchain.cpp where it says: " case TESTNET: start_height = testnet_hard_forks[2].height; break;" testnet_hard_forks[2] is exactly that value 100 to which it somehow sets the current blockchain. I cannot see why rules for HF would impact the way node sees actual blockchain though.

Comment: Update. I changed it to : testnet_hard_forks[] = {
 // version 1 from the start of the blockchain
 { 1, 1, 0, 1341378000 },


 { 7, 901, 0, 1341378000+11900 },

};     and it worked on the node side. However, when I send a version 2 transaction (which my walllet now assembles due to    m_earliest_height[version] = 1000; in node_rpc_proxy.cpp), I get an error message:  "was rejected by daemon with status: Failed
Error: Reason: invalid input"

Comment: Did you make some transactions on each fork version so their is enough inputs for the next fork to pick from?

Comment: hmm, maybe not explicit transfer transactions, but it did have 900 blocks mined. Are coinbase transactions not usable as inputs for ringct v2 tx?

Comment: I am not sure about that, but coinbase transactions are quite specific, so maybe not.  But I'm just guessing here.  It would be cool to have feedbacks from a more competent user than me on this.

Comment: Actually, I believe I was able to resolve it by making the changes I described above in the wallet code and in the node. It just has to catch up to the 1000 blocks I set in the wallet to actually form a proper v2 tx. Thank you for your help el00ruobuob.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve it by adding the following in node_rpc_proxy.cpp

`if(version < 8)
        m_earliest_height[version] = 1000;
        m_earliest_height[version] = 1000`

changing blockchain.cpp at

```
     testnet_hard_forks[] = { 
     { 1, 1, 0, 1341378000 },
 { 7, 901, 0, 1341378000+11900 }, }
```

Wallets generate v2 transactions now and nodes verify them.